# Maven uses wrong repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven project which uses plugins in maven central and the ones which are in intranet Artifactory.

When I run "mvn clean package" (Maven 3.2.1), it successfully builds that BUT on another machine (a new machine with Maven 3.3.9), it picks incorrect repository for one of the plugins which is on maven central and instead uses our intranet Artifactory repository link:

> Failed to transfer file:
>   https://MY_SITE.com/artifactory/plugins-release/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom.
>   Return code is: 500

Why does it happen?
How can I force maven to check central repository first?
Why does it work on another machine but complains on this new machine?

Comment: What do the settings.xml files from both machine looks like?

Answer (score 0):

you might have forgotten to copy your `settings.xml` file from your `~/.m2` folder. Make sure you have the same copies in both the machines.